# Specifying return type 'never' on function expression doesn't work, but it works on function declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-never

```js
function foo(): never {
  throw new Error();
}

const bar = (): never => {
  throw new Error();
}

const qux = function():never {
    throw new Error();
}

function mainFoo(a: number | undefined): number {
  if (a !== undefined) {
    return a;
  }
  foo();
}

function mainBar(a: number | undefined): number {
  if (a !== undefined) {
    return a;
  }
  bar();
}

function mainQux(a: number | undefined): number {
  if (a !== undefined) {
    return a;
  }
  qux();
}
```

<sup>([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKAXIsBTANzwCdEBvAKEUSgAti4B3XPZgUWIeMwG4KBfChQgIAzlEQAjAIakAvIkw58ReQD5yVGvSYt2nONwx9BwsRICOIAB6IFoSLARKVJTdWp0GzfPq68BIQdoeCQAW2kYMAAxVDRpZRAwyTcAH0RwABM8YCi8TOxcJJTSSmoYYEVpRABCOQUsnLyC9w9iPCgQYiRpPmpBahR0Y0CKYKdwyLAAIVl4xOS0jLBs3PwChZLWiqra+uXV5oxW6nbO7sRerQGpOZHTcdDECKiARRt5osXSdMa1-MKYGKbjKiB28T2DRWTXWx1Bpw6XR6fUQNys1gC-CAA))</sup>

In the code above, mainBar and mainQux are exhibiting errors as if the return type of bar() and qux() were 'undefined'.

What's inferred differently?

[image]